# Finding the size of a string in argv using sizeof

Tags: c, pointers, sizeof, argv

This is more of a conceptual question at this point rather than a practical one but it is really bothering me.

Let us say I have a c program called "test.c" and I want to find the number of spaces in array there are for a word the user types in as an argument. For example "./test.c test_run" should print 9 because there are 8 characters and then one for the null terminating character. When I try to use sizeof on argv though I am having some trouble.

```
int  main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char buf10[10];
    printf("The size of buf10 is: %i.\n", sizeof(buf10));
    return 0;
}
```

Prints the result: "**The size of buf10 is: 10.**". This makes sense because I chose a char array. In C, the size of a char is 1 byte. If I chose int, this number would be 4.

Now my question is why can't I do this with argv?

```
int  main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("argv[1] has the value: %s\n", argv[1]);
    printf("strlen of argv[1] is: %i\n", strlen(argv[1]));
    printf("sizeof of argv[1] is: %i\n", sizeof(argv[1]));
    return 0;
}
```

Ran with "./test Hello_SO" gives the output:

```
argv[1] has the value: Hello_SO
strlen of argv[1] is: 8
sizeof of argv[1] is: 4
```

The string length makes sense because it should be 9 but minus the "\0" makes 8.

However I do not understand why sizeof is returning 4 (the size of the pointer). I understand that *argv[] can be thought of as **argv. But I accounted for this already. In my first example i print "buf" but here i print "argv[1]". I know I could easily get the answer by using strlen but as I said earlier this is just conceptual at this point.

Comment: Sounds like you have perhaps answered your own question.

Comment: `argv[1]` has type `char *`, so `sizeof argv[1]` means `sizeof(char *)`. That's what sizeof does.

Comment: But why does buf10 print 10 and argv[1] not print 9. buf10 is also a pointer is it not?

Comment: `buf10` is an array type, not a pointer.

Comment: Out of curiousity, what do you expect `strlen("hello\0world")` to return?

Comment: Following on, would you expect `sizeof "hello\0world"` to follow the pattern you have observed?

Comment: @Seb good example. Since the length of these Char[] should be known at compile time, the first example should print 5 stopping at the terminating character since we want the length of only the string. The second example should print the size, since each character is 1 byte, 5 for hello, 1 for \0, 5 for world, and 1 again for \0. Therefore 12.

Comment: @StevenK Both are available at compile-time; the question is whether the compiler will apply the optimisation in that case. You should use `%zu` to print `size_t` values... Okay, I misunderstood your question initially. Perhaps a more illuminating example: `char *fubar = "hello world";` What kind of value do you expect `sizeof NULL` to produce, compared to `sizeof fubar`? Should `sizeof` attempt to follow the pointer to find out the size of that which is pointed at? If so, then the first example is surely invalid, right?

Comment: Well NULL is defined as (void *)0, so if sizeof followed the pointer, would you get issues between treating 0 as an integer verse treating it as type void?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pointers and arrays are not the same thing, though they are quite similar in many situations.  `sizeof` is a key difference.

```
int arr[10];
assert(sizeof arr == (sizeof(int) * 10));
int *ip;
assert(sizeof ip == sizeof(int*));
```

The type of `arr` above is `int[10]`.  Another way to see the difference between array types and pointers is by trying to assign to them.

```
int i;
ip = &i; // sure, fine
arr = &i; // fails, can't assign to an int[10]
```

arrays cannot be assigned to.

What is most confusing is that when you have an array as a function parameter, it actually *is* the same has having a pointer.

```
int f(int arr[10]) {
    int x;
    arr = &x; // fine, because arr is actually an int*
    assert(sizeof arr == sizeof(int*));
}
```

To address your question of why you can't use `sizeof argv[1]` and get the size of the string (plus the 1 for the `\0`), it's because it's a ragged array.  In this case the first dimension is of unknown size, as well as the second.  `sizeof` behaves like a compile time operation in this case, and the length of the string is not known until run time.

Consider the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof argv[1]);
}
```

The assembly generated for this is:

```
.LC0:
    .string "%zu\n"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB3:
    .cfi_startproc
    subq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    movl    $8, %esi        # this 8 is the result of sizeof
    movl    $.LC0, %edi     # the format string
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf          # calling printf
    movl    $0, %eax
    addq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

as you can see, the result of `sizeof argv[1]` is done at compile time, nothing above is computing the length of the string. I'm on 64-bit so my pointers are 8 bytes.

Comment: The confusion is really caused by the fact that you CANNOT HAVE an array as a function parameter -- if you declare a function parameter as an array, the compiler silently turns it into a pointer for you, "helpfully" concealing any misunderstanding and leading to errors like these.

Comment: @ChrisDodd yes, but don't forget about multidimensional arrays which have different rules.

Comment: No such thing as multidimensional arrays in C -- only arrays of arrays, which turn into pointers when used as arguments, just like any other array.  Then there's also the confusion between arrays of arrays and arrays of pointers, which are completely different despite the fact they can be accessed with the same syntax.

Comment: @ChrisDodd whether or not to call them multidimensional arrays, I'm just pointing out that `int f(int a[][5]) { printf("%zu\n", sizeof a[0]); }` prints `sizeof(int) * 5` not `sizeof(int *)`

Comment: Just to add a comment to your second example Ryan, the reason why that does not work is because int a[10] can be thought of as the type of const int*, therefore it can never change.

Comment: @StevenK I think you mean `int *const`

Answer (score 1):

The buf10 variable is known at compile-time to be a (contiguous) array of ten characters.  The other pointers are dynamically allocated, and are pointers to a character.  This is why you get the size of the character array vs the sizeof(char *).

Comment: So is there a difference between char buf10[10] = "Hello" and char buf10[] = "Hello" then?

Comment: the latter will compute the length of the array based on how much space is needed to store "Hello". so the size of will be 6.  It's still an array though.  If you did `const char *s = "Hello"` then `sizeof s` would be `sizeof(char *)`